# Search Results Web results Parsing string to IP Address doesn't work some time

Tags: c#

im trying for convert String IP to ipAddress but for some string this method not working as well , what is the problem? 
ex:

```
                Console.WriteLine("ip address");
                string ip = Console.ReadLine();
                System.Net.IPAddress IP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                Console.WriteLine(IP);
```

for example if i use this string "192.168.001.011" then the IPAddress.Parse method will return me 192.168.1.9
or "192.168.1.012" will return '192.168.1.10'
why ?? 
i'm confused really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPAddress.Parse treats leading zeros as octal which is why you're getting an unexpected result.

This worked for me.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
..
..
    Console.WriteLine("ip address");
    string ip = Console.ReadLine();
    //Remove the leading zeroes with Regex...
    ip = Regex.Replace(ip, "0*([0-9]+)", "${1}");
    System.Net.IPAddress IP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    Console.WriteLine(IP);
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with this cod:

```
Console.WriteLine("ip address");
string ip = Console.ReadLine();
string[] s = ip.Split('.');
IPAddress IP= IPAddress.Parse(Int16.Parse(s[0]) + "." + Int16.Parse(s[1]) + "." + 
Int16.Parse(s[2]) + "." + Int16.Parse(s[3]));
Console.WriteLine(IP);
```

but your way is better i think... Thanks alot